# MongoDB aggregation: grouping distinct nested values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using Mongo v4.4
I have a few thousand documents in a collection. Every document has an array of address data, like so:

```js
"addresses": [
  {
    "state": "New York",
    "city": "New York"
  },
  {
    "state": "New York",
    "city": "Buffalo"
  },
  {
    "state": "Massachusetts",
    "city": "Boston"
  },
  ...
]
```

Across all documents, I want to generate a list of distinct `city` values, grouped by `state`:

```js
[
  {
    "state": "New York",
    "cities": [
      "New York",
      "Buffalo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "state": "Massachusetts",
    "cities": [
      "Boston"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I've gotten pretty close, but not quite there. This query seems to do almost exactly what I want, except it isn't getting all the data and I do not know why. I've verified that the collection does include all 50 states, but it's only returning 20 states. Perhaps it is only aggregating over a single document?

```js
db.locations.aggregate([
  { $unwind: {path: "$addresses" }},
  { $group: {
      _id: "$addresses.state",
      cities: { $addToSet: '$addresses.city' }
    }
  }
])
```

Meanwhile, this query returns all the states and all the licenses, all the data I want, but they're not grouped. It's all dumped into two unordered arrays. Presumably the glitch has to do with the `$group: { _id: ...` value, but after a few hours of tinkering I still don't know precisely.

```js
db.locations.aggregate([
  { $unwind: {path: "$addresses" }},
  { $group: {
      _id: null,
      states: { $addToSet: '$addresses.state' },
      cities: { $addToSet: '$addresses.city' }
    }
  }
])
```

I do not have much experience writing mongo queries using the aggregation pipeline, so explanation will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running Query in mongo compass? if yes it takes only first 100,000 records so you may see partial result. you can run this command in mongo shell(latest version),

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Query in mongo compass? if yes it takes only first 100,000 records so you may see partial result. you can run this command in mongo shell(latest version),  You should get result  as

```
db.locations.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$addresses"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$addresses.state",
      cities: {
        $addToSet: "$addresses.city"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Should give you expected result. in mongo compass you can see output of each pipeline stage in your case unwind will create n documents for given address and then that many records will be used to do group stage where it will group by state and  addtoset will give you that cities unique list.

if you wish to debug missing states then filter data for that state and see what result you get

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "addresses.state": "New York" //missing state
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$addresses"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$addresses.state",
      cities: {
        $addToSet: "$addresses.city"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you still have issue and if you can share sample documents then we can try running above aggregation.